# Laravel - Bind parameters when using DB::raw() on a join

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a query that requires a join using `DB::raw()`. It's joining a `JSON_TABLE()` so it's a little different compared to what people normally do. I've got it working but I can't seem to get it to work when binding parameters.

Here's the code:

```php
if(!isset($request->search['merchantId']) && isset($request->search['uuid']['division'])) {

  $query->join(DB::raw('JSON_TABLE(
                      \'[{"division":"'.$request->search['uuid']['division'].'"}]\',
                      \'$[*]\' COLUMNS (
                              division VARCHAR(32) PATH \'$.division\'
                          )
                      ) jt1'), 'jt1.division', 'entitiesConsolidation.division');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use binding of laravel by `[ key => value]` or `setBindings` method

```
$query->join(DB::raw('JSON_TABLE(
                  \'[{"division":":division"}]\',
                  \'$[*]\' COLUMNS (
                          division VARCHAR(32) PATH \'$.division\'
                      )
                  ) jt1', ['division' => $request->search['uuid']['division']]), 'jt1.division', 'entitiesConsolidation.division');
```

Comment: I've already tried that but it doesn't work. From what I've read you can't bind like that when using DB:raw.

Answer (score 0):

Build the JSON value with `json_array()` & `json_object()` and use `addBinding()`:

```php
if(!isset($request->search['merchantId']) && isset($request->search['uuid']['division'])) {
    $query->join(DB::raw('JSON_TABLE(
              json_array(json_object(\'division\', ?)),
              \'$[*]\' COLUMNS (
                      division VARCHAR(32) PATH \'$.division\'
                  )
              ) jt1'), 'jt1.division', 'entitiesConsolidation.division');

    $query->addBinding($request->search['uuid']['division'], 'join');
}
```